# Why does GACUtil claim to install an assembly to the GAC but fail in reality?

Tags: gac

I have an assembly: **SomeAssembly.dll**

I have GACUtil's folder on my path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools**

I change to the folder where SomeAssembly.dll is, execute

```
GACUtil /i SomeAssembly.dll
```

The response is:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

I check **C:\Windows\Assembly**, but my assembly does not appear to be there.

I return to my command window (which I note has **Administrator** rights) and type:

```
GACUtil /l SomeAssembly.dll
```

and the response confirms...

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:

Number of items = 0
```

So It seems SomeAssembly.dll is not in the GAC

**Why?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leave off the `.dll` extension when using `gacutil /l` and it should correctly report your assembly.

Also, I suspect there might be some sort of 32/64-bit mixup going on. When you're viewing `C:\Windows\Assembly` via Windows Explorer, you're likely seeing the 32-bit GAC only.

[**UPDATE:** looks like .NET 4 stores GAC assemblies in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` so you're only see CLR v2.0 assemblies in `C:\Windows\assembly`.]

To look at the real contents of the (v2 CLR) GAC directory view it without the Explorer shell extension - a quick way to do this is to map a drive to the directory using `subst` and view it through that, e.g.:

```
C:\>subst G: c:\Windows\assembly
C:\>start G:
```

Comment: Also, make sure that the assembly's name matches the name of the DLL. If they don't, then you need to "/l" with the assembly's "proper" name, rather than its filename.

Comment: Also if you want to remove the dll from the GAC you need to miss the .dll extension off when doing gacutil /u